# cant access google play store

Tags: google-play-store

i lost my first gmail account password and have tried using other passwords like excellency, excellently and so on to see if i can access it but to no avail so i re-opened a new account  with the name johneunice025 yesterday and still  i cant use it to access google play store rather my first account keeps on appearing for me to add my password and log in which i cant remember anymore. pls what do i do?

Comment: Why don't you try and recovery the password  For gmail? Click on the forgot password and follow instructions

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new account does not automatically add it to your phone. You have to add your new account in Settings -> Accounts&Sync.

Keep in mind that, as **beeshyams** correctly mentioned, using another google account you will not be able to restore any of your paid apps or any game data.

Comment: Your solution is partial. He can't get his installed/paid apps /games. You can't transfer from one account to another. How would you want OP to do that?

Comment: @beeshyams Well, you're right, but I don't see any word mentioning restoring paid apps or transferring data in the Question.

Comment: That is the reason I didn't down vote. Maybe you can add that to your answer so that OP gets the full picture.Also the reason why I suggested that he should try and recover his pass word

Comment: @beeshyams Already added :)